# What is the type of a file that starts with '%TSD-Header-###'?

Tags: android-studio, file

We have a Git Merge Request in which the changed java files are considered as binaries.

On the branch there is not any kind of `gitattributes` file, which could make Git consider a text file as a binary.

With `file filename`, it returns `filename data` instead of `filename ASCII text`.

With `cat -vt filename` or `vi filename`, we can see it starts with `%TSD-Header-###`. I googled it and also `TDS header` but didn't find what it exactly is. Some say it's some kind of encrypted format. But if so, I should have easily found many results like a Wiki page.

We doubt it was created by the text editor. The committer used Android Studio to edit the files and made the commit. Here is the version info of Android Studio.

```
Android Studio Flamingo | 2022.2.1
Build #AI-222.4459.24.2221.9862592, built on March 31, 2023
Runtime version: 17.0.6+0-b2043.56-9586694 amd64
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o.
Windows 10 10.0
GC: G1 Young Generation, G1 Old Generation
Memory: 1280M
Cores: 8
Registry:
    external.system.auto.import.disabled=true
    ide.text.editor.with.preview.show.floating.toolbar=false
    gradle.version.catalogs.dynamic.support=true

Non-Bundled Plugins:
    com.seclab.lintcheckplugin (2.0.11)
    GsonFormatPlus (1.6.1)
    GsonFormat-Plus (1.6.5)
    de.ohmesoftware.parcelablegenerator (0.7.1)
    com.moxun.plugin.s2v (1.9.0)
```

What is it? How can we create it or cancel it? Thanks for any help.